# Routing and multiple parameters in a web api controller

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, routes

I know this has been asked a lot of times but nobody really wraps it up.

I'm currently using a .NET Core Backend which has a web api controller.

I know that there are multiple ways of handling the routing in .NET Core e.g.

**Using Constraints**

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public string GetById(int id)
{
    return "item " + id;
}
```

**Creating Default Routes**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**Building RESTful Routes**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"hello", "world!"};
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostCreate([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }
}
```

and a couple more options.

However I just can't figure out how to pass multiple parameters in one route.

In my case I have to update two different objects at the same time and have to use either an HTTP Patch or HTTP Put request.

I could go with something like **api/ExampleName/Id** but what I need is something like **api/ExampleName/ObjectOneID&ObjectTwoID**

Does anyone know how to build something like this?

I thought about creating a default route in the startup file and configure it right there. However I suppose it wants a specific syntax in order to read multiple parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters in the URI's themselves - like `http://myapi.com/api/{controller}/{action}?id=someId&anotherId=someOtherId`

Your action method would then be like

`public void PostCreate([FromUri]Guid someId, [FromUri]Guid anotherId)`

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<string> Patch([FromBody] Model request)
```

where `Model` is

```
class Model 
{
   public int ObjectOneID {get; set;}
   public int ObjectTwoID {get; set;}
}
```

to use it just create request with body that contains `ObjectOneID` and `ObjectTwoID` like

```
PATCH api/ExampleName
Content-Type: application/json
{
   "ObjectOneID":1,
   "ObjectTwoID":2
}
```

Comment: I think I should explain my case a bit better. 
I have to update two objects of the same class. Both ojects already have a unique ID in the database.
What I expected is to receive both objects with two different bodys and create an Sql Statement which alters the data of those two objects based on the body

Comment: @Ekos Ok, it is nice but question about "**Routing** and multiple parameters in a web api controller". Not about updating entity in database

Comment: Updating the entity is just the result of what I want to achieve right now.
I have to build a route hence routing with multiple parameters.
In other words I cant get my controller to recognize different parameters. I just dont know how to build a route like that

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I suggest to use **POST/PUT with model**

```
[Route("dummy")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Dummy(Foo req)
{
    //logic
}

public class Foo
{
    public CustomObjectBody ObjectOneID {get;set;}
    public CustomObjectBody ObjectTwoID {get;set;}
}

public class CustomObjectBody
{
    public int Property1 {get;set;}
    public int Property2 {get;set;}
}
```